# Markdown in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

What will be the best way to implement Markdown in Thymeleaf?

- template mode
- a new dialect (what processors?)

It would be useful if I can embed markdown in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood from Javadoc, I will have to implement first the markdown enabler as an `AbstractAttributeModelProcessor` and use `structureHandler.setLocalVariable` to set that variable. Then I have to implement the markdown executor as an `AbstractTextProcessor` and in the `doProcess` method to test the variable using `context.getVariable` and if set to replace the text with a new one: `text.setText(transformMarkdown(..))`.

See more at https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/439.